# Error al mostrar todos los checkbox activados

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php include('php/verificarSesion.php');?>
<?php    

//Almacenando el id del grupo de usuarios recibido mediante GET de la pagina grupos.php

if(isset($_GET['id_grupo_usuarios']) && (!empty($_GET['id_grupo_usuarios']))  && is_numeric($_GET['id_grupo_usuarios']) == 1){

   $id_grupo_usuarios = $_GET['id_grupo_usuarios'];

}else{
   
    echo "<script>
        window.location.href='verGrupo.php';
    </script>";}

?>


<?php include("plantillas/header.php"); ?>

<!-- CONTENDIO DE LA PAGINA (permisosChex.php)-->
<section class="listadoPacientes">
<div class="container mt-3">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-6 col-md-5">
            <h2>Asignar permisos al grupo <?php echo $id_grupo_usuarios;?></h2>
            <p>Aquí puede consultar los permisos que pertenecen a este grupo</p>
         </div>
  
         <div class="col-4" id="tabla">  
            <table id="tablaPacientes" class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="width:100%">  
               <thead>
                  <tr>
                   
                     <th>Permisos</th>

                         
                  </tr>
               </thead>
                    <tbody>

                     <!--INICIO DEL FORMULARIO DE ENVIO DE DATOS-->

                          <form class="row formularioCrearPaciente" action="php/asignarPermisos.php" method="post" id="FormularioActualizarPaciente">
                        <input type="text" value="<?php   echo $id_grupo_usuarios; ?>" name="id_grupo_usuarios">  
<?php include("php/conexion.php")?>


<?php

//consulta para mostrar todos los permisos
$sql = "SELECT * FROM permisos ORDER BY id DESC";

$resultado = $conexion->query($sql);

$listadoPermisos = array('data' => array());


     
   if($resultado->num_rows > 0) { 

//mostraremos una numeracion en la tabla>>>>numeracion: 1, 2, 3....

$numeracion = 0;
 while($fila = $resultado->fetch_array()) { 

    $numeracion = $numeracion + 1;
   
   //aqui se almacena el id del permiso

   $id_permiso = $fila[0];
    $nombre = $fila['nombre'];
```

En esta segunda consulta obtengo los permisos asignados a un grupo de usuarios

```
$consulta2 = "SELECT id_permisos FROM tiene_asignado where id_grupo = $id_grupo_usuarios";

                  $resultados = $conexion->query($consulta2);

                  while( $asignados = $resultados->fetch_array()){

                         //aqui almaceno los permisos de los checkbox selecionados
         
         $datos=array();

    if (is_array($asignados) == true) {

      //asigno una variable para cada checkbox seleccionado en el array
         foreach($asignados as $asignado)

      {
```

relaciono los permisos seleccionados del checkbox con el campo id_permisos d la tabla (tiene_asignado)

```
            $datos[$asignados['id_permisos']] = true;

         } 
         }else{//FIN DE is_array($asignados) 

            //esto es solo una prueba
               echo "nada";
            }

   ?>
   
   <tr>
   
      <td>  
       <?php echo $numeracion;?>
       
        <input title='Crear ficha de <?php echo $id_grupo_usuarios?>' type="checkbox" name="permisos[]" value="<?php echo $id_permiso;?>" class="delete-checkbox" <?php echo isset($datos[$fila[0]]) ? 'checked' : '';?> >
     
  

      
    </tr
```

Solo puedo ver los permisos asignados al grupo cuando incluyo el input checkbox dentro del segundo WHILE si no lo hago asi, el problema esta en que tambien se me repiten los inputs, es decir, si un grupo tiene asignado 3 permisos, cada uno d los inputs se repiten tres veces pero me senala los 3 permisos que tiene asignados ese grupo

```
 <?php   } //FIN DEL SEGUNDO WHILE?>

 <?php   } //FIN DEL PRIMER WHILE?>
          <?php     

             } //FIN DE IF?>

<?php  ?>
<div class="col-md-6 form-group">
<button type="submit"id="ActualizarPaciente" class="btn btn-primary">Asignar Permisos</button>
</div>
      </form>
<?php


?>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

               

                    </tbody>
            </table> 
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</section>


<!-- FIN CONTENDIO DE LA PAGINA -->
<!-- Incluyendo el footer de la pagina  -->
<?php include('plantillas/footer.php'); ?>
<!-- script js que contiene las funcionalidades de la pagina del listado de pacientes  -->
<!--<script src="js/verpermisosChex.js"></script>-->
```

Comment: Hazte un ejemplo mínimo y vete probando a ver en qué falla...

Comment: ¿de donde sacas el **$id_grupo_usuarios**?  No veo que salga de ninguna parte

Comment: Demasiadas cosas mal para darte una respuesta que sea útil a los demás. Corrije lo siguiente y si sigues con problemas, edita esta pregunta y plantea el nuevo escenario: 1) En el HTML usas al mismo nivel dos `col-`, que sumadas, superan las 12 columnas de bootstrap, son col-9 y col-4.  2) Dentro del ciclo **while** hay otra consulta (**$consulta2**), que sólo hace falta ejecutar una **única** vez, y no en cada ciclo. 3) Con `$asignados = $resultados->fetch_array();` solo vas a conseguir **un** único registro. Usa **while ($asignados = $resultados->fetch_array())**.  Tambien hay errores de HTML

Comment: Hola @masterguru, el $id_grupo_usuarios se encuentra mas arriba, lo omiti por creer k no seria necesario ya que mi problema es mostrar los permisos. `<?php    

//Almacenando el id del grupo de usuarios recibido mediante GET de la pagina asignarPermisos.php

if(isset($_GET['id_grupo_usuarios']) && (!empty($_GET['id_grupo_usuarios']))  && is_numeric($_GET['id_grupo_usuarios']) == 1){

   $id_grupo_usuarios = $_GET['id_grupo_usuarios'];

  // echo $id_grupo_usuarios;


}else{
   
    echo "<script>
        window.location.href='verGrupo.php';
    </script>";}

?>`

Comment: @user287003 Hola, ejem... esto no es un chat, los comentarios son para decir cosas concretas que puedo o no puedo responder yo mismo, son para todos :-)  Si has conseguido avanzar en lo que te he dicho puedes editar la pregunta pulsando sobre el enlace [edit] que aparece en gris a pie de pregunta, y así podremos ayudarte mejor

Comment: @user287003 vale, pues ponlo en la pregunta tal como acabo de explicarte en mi anterior comentario y corrije las otras cosas para que podamos ayudarte a partir de ahi